# ruby HttpClient library closing socket after response with persistent connection?

Tags: ruby, http, tcp

I'm using the HTTPClient gem (http://github.com/nahi/httpclient) for ruby, to post data to IIS 6.1. Even though both support HTTP 1.1 it seems to be closing the socket after each request made, rather than using persistent connections. I haven't added any flags to enable persistent connections (mainly because having poked about the source code it appears that they should be enabled by default).

The reason I think the socket is being close is that if I watch the requests in Wireshark once each request is made I see FIN/ACK TCP packets sent from the client to the server, then the same sent back the other way.

Am I misreading that or does that mean the socket is being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia's article on TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination) suggests that the FIN/ACK packets are a signal to terminate the connection. Check which of the client or server initiated the sending of the FIN packet - that's the party requesting that the connection is closed.

As you saw in the source, an [HTTP 1.1 implementation should assume that connections are persistent by default](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1).

Is the client specifying HTTP 1.1 in its request and is the server responding accordingly?